# If class name has a special character, do this

Tags: jquery, html

I have several divs that has two class names, for example...

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="test word1.20">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="test word3.40">
    </div>
</div>
```

If a decimal exists in 2nd class name, I would like to remove the decimal AND the zero at the end, so the outcome would be like word12. Note that I have several divs like this

I'm thinking...

```
if .test has a decimal, do this {
    $(".container .test").each(function() {
       value1 = $(this).attr("class").replace(".", "");
       value2 = $(this).attr("class").replace("0", "");
       $(this).attr("class", value1);
       $(this).attr("class", value2);
    });
}
```

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: the first challenge is that you need to get the class name then you can proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate HTML of `.container` as below:

```js
$(function(){
  processReplacement();
  showResult();
});

processReplacement = function(){
  $("div.test").each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).prop('class');
    var regex   = /(\bword)(.*)\b/;
    
    var decimalClassName = regex.exec(classes)[2];
    var decimalClassNameFixed = parseFloat(decimalClassName).toString().replace('.', '');
    
    $(this).prop('class', classes.replace(regex, "$1" + decimalClassNameFixed));
  });
};

showResult = function(){
  $('.test').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).prop('class'));
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="test word1.20"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="test word3.40"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Duc! This works even when there's no decimal (ex, word50) or there's only a single digit (ex, word5). It will ONLY change the class name with a decimal. Appreciate it!